# convert "2014-05" into date format as "May 2015" for display in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have date in this character format "2017-03" and I want to convert it in "March 2017" for display in ggplot in R. But when I try to convert it using as.Date("2017-03","%Y-%m") it gives NA

Comment: You need `format(as.Date("2017-03-01"), "%B %Y")`

Comment: You can consider using `zoo::yearmon` type.  `zoo::as.yearmon("2014-05", "%Y-%m")` will return you as:
#[1] "May 2014"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider using `zoo::as.yearmon` function as:

```
library(zoo)

#Sample data
v <- c("2014-05", "2017-03")

as.yearmon(v, "%Y-%m")
#[1] "May 2014" "Mar 2017"

#if you want the month name to be in full. Then you can format yearmon type as
format(as.yearmon(v, "%Y-%m"), "%B %Y")
#[1] "May 2014"   "March 2017"
```

Comment: Note that "%Y-%m" is the default so it could be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Parse dates back and forth can be done like this:

The one you mentioned is done by quoting MKR:
Use zoo package

```
library(zoo)
date <- "2017-03"
as.yearmon(date, "%Y-%m")
#[1] "Mar 2017"
format(as.yearmon(date, "%Y-%m"), "%B %Y")
#[1] "March 2017"
```

If you want to parse March 2017 or other similar formats back to 2017-03:
Use hms package because base R doesn't provide a nice built-in class for date

```
library(hms)
DATE <- "March 1 2017"
parse_date(DATE, "%B %d %Y")
#[1] "2017-03-01"
```

Or if you are parsing dates with foreign language:

```
foreign_date <- "1 janvier 2018"
parse_date(foreign_date, "%d %B %Y", locale = locale("fr"))
#[1] "2018-01-01"
```

By using the locale = locale("language") you can parse dates with foreign months names to standard dates. Use this to check the language:

```
date_names_langs()
```

-Format:

-Year: %Y(4 digits)  %y(2 digits; 00-69->2000-2069, 70-99 -> 1970-1999)

-Month: %m (2 digits), %b (abbreviation: Jan), %B full name January

-Day: %d (2 digits)